# Mixed-effect modelling including factor with NA

Tags: r, mixed-model, missing-data

I'm analysing reaction time data using mixed-effect modelling in R.  Data comes from 2 types of participant groups: native speakers and non-native speakers.  For the non-natives, I have proficiency scores (estimating their mastery of English).  The proficiency of native speakers is irrelevant, and coded as NA.  Does this mean that lmer will consider proficiency as a factor only for non-native speakers?

```
'data.frame':   8373 obs. of  17 variables:
$Subject       : Factor w/ 21 levels 
$L1            : Factor w/ 3 levels "English","German",..: 
$Proficiency   : Factor w/ 12 levels:"0","0.6","0.61",..: 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...  
$Target        : Factor w/ 243 levels 
$Relation      : Factor w/ 4 levels 
$Word.Order    : Factor w/ 2 levels "HeadMod*","ModHead"
$Priming       : Factor w/ 2 levels "PrHead","PrMod"
$Trial         : Factor w/ 481 levels 
$Target.RTinv  : num
```

I'm concerned that when I add Proficiency to my model, the AIC and BIC become negative. Is this something to be concerned about?

```
Models:
dat.lmer5: -1000 * Target.RTinv ~ (1 | Subject) + (1 | Target) + L1 + Word.Order + Priming
dat.lmer8: -1000 * Target.RTinv ~ (1 | Subject) + (1 | Target) + L1 + Word.Order + Priming + Proficiency
          Df     AIC     BIC  logLik  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
dat.lmer5  8 1859.68 1915.92 -921.84
dat.lmer8 17 -438.62 -329.59  236.31 2316.3      9  < 2.2e-16 ***
```

Comment: Can you post a `str` of your data and the call to `lmer`? However, from your description I have a wild guesses: Yes, `lmer` only uses proficiency scores when available.

Comment: dat.lmer8 = lmer(-1000 * Target.RTinv ~ (1|Subject) + (1|Target) + L1 + Word.Order + Priming + Proficiency, dat, REML=TRUE)

Comment: My guess (I am almost sure, but Henrik's comment is making me a little uncertain) is that if you include proficiency as a factor, all observations with proficiency = NA are excluded, so you would not actually have any native speakers left!

Comment: Why is proficiency a factor?  It looks continuous from the little information given.  (0, 0.6, 0.61, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only uses data from complete cases, so the ones with `NA` are not being included in the second model at all.  This makes the AIC/BIC incomparable, as it only makes sense to use AIC/BIC to compare models based on the same data.

Look at the output from `summary` to confirm, and to see how many observations were included in each model.

The negative isn't a problem, though; the actual value has little interpretable meaning; what matters is how different the values are.  Smaller is always better; so if they're both negative, the more negative value is better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very clear explanation.  How do you suggest I take Proficiency into account if I want to keep all my participants in, even those without a proficiency score? (And I guess you're right, it should be treated as continuous, so that was a newbie mistake to start with...)

Comment: Just give all native speakers the same proficiency value; they'll get a different offset because of the native/non-native term.  (0 is probably preferred for interpretation of the coefficients, but technically, any value will result in the same fit.)

Comment: Perfect.  Works fine now, and (FYI) the AIC and BIC now remain positive.  Thanks!

Comment: Please allow me a follow-up: How can I ascertain the effect of proficiency for the non-natives?  I've tried modelling it as an interaction between language group and proficiency, but I get an error.
`dat.lmer14 = lmer(-1000 * Target.RTinv ~ (1|Subject) + (1|Target) + Proficiency*L1 + (Word.Order + L1 + Priming)^3, dat, REML=TRUE)`
Error in mer_finalize(ans) : Downdated X'X is not positive definite, 8.

Comment: The effect of proficiency is only for the non-natives because they're the only ones with proficiency values; you don't need the interaction.

Comment: Sorry for being slow, but didn't you advise me to give the native speakers a proficiency value to make sure their data was included in the model? I gave them 1 (i.e.100%).

Comment: That's correct; I see now my last message was unclear.  Since the native speakers all have the same proficiency values, you don't need the interaction, because a change in response associated with a change in proficiency only makes sense for non-native speakers.

Comment: Thank you.  Does that mean that effectively the difference between the 1 value for native speakers and the several values for non-natives does not have an impact on the model, or at least that this impact is minimal?

Comment: Just re-ran the analysis with 0 instead of 1 for native speaker proficiency and obtained identical results.  So: no impact.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Really?  I would have thought the coefficient for native/nonnative would have changed.  But maybe I'm overthinking this.  Or perhaps you considered that an identical fit (which it would be)?

Comment: I get the same fit and the same coefficient for Proficiency, but upon closer inspection the values for the (Intercept) and L1 (i.e. language groups) change dramatically.  (Everything else appears to stay the same.)  How should I interpret this? See [illustration](http://tinyurl.com/d8twfcp) with the same model fitted on 2 data sets: dat3(English proficiency = 1) vs dat (English proficiency = 0)

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought.  That's the difference in offset due to the proficiency term being 1 instead of 0.  Just be careful with what you're comparing and you'll be fine.